# Python: how can I check whether an object is of type datetime.date?

Tags: python, datetime

I have tried a few obvious options but none of them works:

```
In [150]: x
Out[150]: datetime.date(2012, 9, 1)

In [151]: type(x)
Out[151]: datetime.date

In [152]: isinstance(x, datetime.date)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-9a298ea6fce5> in <module>()
----> 1 isinstance(x, datetime.date)

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types

In [153]: x is datetime.date
Out[153]: False

In [154]: type(x) is datetime.date
Out[154]: False
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Can you produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? I should think a four- or five-line program would suffice. I [cannot reproduce your results](http://ideone.com/gqdou2) from what you have already posted.

Comment: What Python version are you using? For Python-2.6 `isinstance(x, datetime.date)` works fine as does `type(x) is datetime.date`

Comment: Which version of Python are you using, and what did you do to generate `x`?

Comment: x should not matter, it is complaining about arg 2 of `isinstance`, his `datetime.date` class is borked for some reason

Comment: Could you check your imports? This line is actually missing in your snippet. The error message hints at something like "from datetime import date, datetime". But it must be "import datetime".

Comment: if it's dataframe, you can use `df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64])`

Answer (score 161, accepted):

i believe the reason it is not working in your example is that you have imported `datetime` like so :

```
from datetime import datetime
```

this leads to the error you see

```
In [30]: isinstance(x, datetime.date)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/<ipython-input-30-9a298ea6fce5> in <module>()
----> 1 isinstance(x, datetime.date)

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

if you simply import like so :

```
import datetime
```

the code will run as shown in all of the other answers

```
In [31]: import datetime

In [32]: isinstance(x, datetime.date)
Out[32]: True

In [33]:
```

Comment: If you have a datetime (instead of just a date), by extension you can do: `x = datetime.datetime.now()` then `isinstance(x, datetime.datetime)`

Comment: Well, if you'd like to distinguish datetime.date and datetime.datetime this method will fail:
`>>> import datetime`
`>>> foo = datetime.datetime.now()`
`>>> isinstance(foo, datetime.date)`
`True`
.__class__ should help
`>>> foo.__class__ == datetime.date`
`False`
`>>> foo.__class__ == datetime.datetime`
`True`

Comment: In order to differentiate between "datetime.date" and "datetime.date" classes you should use `type(x) is datetime.date` after importing the "datetime" library as explained here.

Comment: Why not use type? I've done it, but noone mentioned it. Is it taboo or something?
I always `from datetime import datetime`, it's very rare for me not to.

`if isinstance(dt, type(datetime.now()))`

Comment: Thanks, @BernarditoLuis for the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 24):

In Python 3.8.4 it can be checked that the method with `isinstance` will fail when checking if a `datetime` is whether a `date` or a `datetime` as both checks will give `True`.

```py
    >>> from datetime import datetime, date
    >>> mydatetime = datetime.now()
    >>> mydate = mydatetime.date()
    >>> isinstance(mydatetime, datetime)
    True
    >>> isinstance(mydatetime, date)
    True
```

This is due to the fact that [`datetime` is a subclass of `date`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cd0ff9bd14d6a60e841d10f8415827db556ae622/Lib/datetime.py#L1668) as it is explained in [this other answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549854/13180090)

> an instance of a derived class is an instance of a base class, too

Therefore, when distinguishing between `datetime` and `date`, `type` should be used instead:

```py
    >>> type(mydatetime) is date
    False
    >>> type(mydate) is date
    True
    >>> type(mydate) is datetime
    False
    >>> type(mydatetime) is datetime
    True
```

You can use `==` instead of `is` to compare the type as well (thanks [Tim Tisdall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918558/tim-tisdall) for the heads up), but [there is a difference between `==` and `is`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is) and there might be a performance difference.

Comment: Thanks, ran into this when migrating an old codebase to newer Python.

Comment: I wonder if it's better to use `is` instead of `==` here...

Answer (score 22):

right way is

```
import datetime
isinstance(x, datetime.date)
```

When I try this on my machine it works fine.  You need to look into why `datetime.date` is not a class.  Are you perhaps masking it with something else? or not referencing it correctly for your import?

Comment: The example in the question shows this not working. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: cmd's solution also returns True if x is a datetime.datetime. This may not be what you want or expect. Simon Steinberger's answer properly discriminates between datetime.date and datetime.datetime.

Comment: @cmd In python 2.7 the statement "isinstance(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.date)" returns True.

Comment: Thats true.  datetime.datetime object is a datetime.date through inheritance.  If you want to distinguish between datetime.datetime objects and datetime.date objects check for `if sinstance(x, datetime.datetime)` first then `elif isinstance(x, datetime.date)`  since datetime is a date but date is not a datetime.

Answer (score 18):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html) class `date` is a parent for class `datetime`. And `isinstance()` method will give you `True` in all cases. If you need to distinguish `datetime` from `date` you should check name of the class

```py
import datetime

datetime.datetime.now().__class__.__name__ == 'date' #False
datetime.datetime.now().__class__.__name__ == 'datetime' #True
datetime.date.today().__class__.__name__ == 'date' #True
datetime.date.today().__class__.__name__ == 'datetime' #False
```

I've faced with this problem when i have different formatting rules for dates and dates with time

Answer (score 17):

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date(2012, 9, 1)
print type(d) is datetime.date

> True
```

Comment: Using `is` instead of `==` is more idiomatic way of doing it: `print type(d) is datetime.date`.

Comment: Using type() for type checking is discouraged and unwise, the proper way is to do isinstance.

Comment: In this case, type() works as expected for both datetime.date and datetime.datetime. isinstance(x, datetime.date) returns True if x is a datetime.date or a datetime.datetime.

Comment: @SpankMe: Thanks, I've adapted the answer.

Comment: Using `is` instead of `==` is a premature optimization that might break. There is no reason to test for object identity here (it is likely to work in many cases until it doesn't). You should mention that `type()` is used instead of `isinstance()`, to reject subclasses such as `datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 7):

If your existing code is already relying on `from datetime import datetime`, you can also simply also import `date`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
print isinstance(datetime.today().date(), date)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.5, `isinstance(x, date)` works to me:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> x = date(2012, 9, 1)
>>> type(x)
<class 'datetime.date'>
>>> isinstance(x, date)
True
>>> type(x) is date
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **freezegun** package in **tests** you may need to have more **smart isinstance checks** which works well with **FakeDate** and original **Date/Datetime** beeing inside **with freeze_time context**:

```
def isinstance_date(value):
    """Safe replacement for isinstance date which works smoothly also with Mocked freezetime"""
    import datetime
    if isinstance(value, datetime.date) and not isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
        return True
    elif type(datetime.datetime.today().date()) == type(value):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def isinstance_datetime(value):
    """Safe replacement for isinstance datetime which works smoothly also with Mocked freezetime """
    import datetime
    if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
        return True
    elif type(datetime.datetime.now()) == type(value):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and **tests to verify the implementation**

```
class TestDateUtils(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.date_orig = datetime.date(2000, 10, 10)
        self.datetime_orig = datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 10)

        with freeze_time('2001-01-01'):
            self.date_freezed = datetime.date(2002, 10, 10)
            self.datetime_freezed = datetime.datetime(2002, 10, 10)

    def test_isinstance_date(self):
        def check():
            self.assertTrue(isinstance_date(self.date_orig))
            self.assertTrue(isinstance_date(self.date_freezed))
            self.assertFalse(isinstance_date(self.datetime_orig))
            self.assertFalse(isinstance_date(self.datetime_freezed))
            self.assertFalse(isinstance_date(None))

        check()
        with freeze_time('2005-01-01'):
            check()

    def test_isinstance_datetime(self):
        def check():
            self.assertFalse(isinstance_datetime(self.date_orig))
            self.assertFalse(isinstance_datetime(self.date_freezed))
            self.assertTrue(isinstance_datetime(self.datetime_orig))
            self.assertTrue(isinstance_datetime(self.datetime_freezed))
            self.assertFalse(isinstance_datetime(None))

        check()
        with freeze_time('2005-01-01'):
            check()
```