# Python Datetime and date types

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

Slightly different question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151402/python-how-can-i-check-whether-an-object-is-of-type-datetime-date). Are datetime.date objects a subset of datetime.datetime objects? Are there instances when a variable may be both a datetime.date type AND a datetime.datetime object?

Below, I make a datetime.datetime object that also seems to validate as a datetime.date object. Thoughts?

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: x = datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 13, 13, 0)

In [3]: isinstance(x, datetime.date)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: isinstance(x, datetime.datetime)
Out[4]: True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `datetime.datetime` is a subclass of `datetime.date`.

```
>>> issubclass(datetime.datetime, datetime.date)
True
```

So for an instance of `datetime.datetime`, `isinstance(instance, datetime.date)` will return `True`. But it returns `False` if the two reverse.

```
>>> date = datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
>>> isinstance(date, datetime.datetime)
False
>>>
```

Comment: Ah ha, thanks @zhangyangyu. (Poor form, but another question)... is there an idiomatic way to distinguish between the two other than what you describe above?

Comment: Quite sorry I am not an experienced coder and don't know an idiomatic way. But try this `x.__class__ == datetime.datetime` returns `True` and `x.__class__ == datetime.date` returns `False`. @Pete