# How do you use the type function to return a boolean value in Python

Tags: python

I have a mixture of `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.time` objects so I cannot use `isinstance` because `isinstance` throws an error if the object is datetime.datetime.  So I need to use the `type` function.  If I have the following:

```
>>>type(tim1)
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Then how do I get:

```
assert type(tim1) == '<class "datetime.datetime">
```

to output `True`.?

Comment: How do you import `datetime`?  This is most likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151402/python-how-can-i-check-whether-an-object-is-of-type-datetime-date

Comment: What error are you getting from `isinstance`, exactly? Give a [mcve], that is exactly what you need and should work fine if you're using it correctly. And why would you expect the result of calling `type` to be a *string?!*

Comment: The error I'm getting is arg2 of isinstance must be a type or tuple of types.  But I'm not worried about the error, what I really want to know is how to return a boolean value using the type function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, as far as why I expect the result of type to be a string, I don't, but I had to choose some object because I don't know what type the obj is.

Comment: @robertford you are probably checking the arguments in the wrong order.  It's `isinstance(object, classinfo)`

Comment: So did you read that error message? What were you passing instead of a type or tuple of types? **Give an example**, [edit] the question. `isinstance` is the correct tool for your task, but if you were passing the same wrong thing to it you're testing against the `type` result, for example, of course it's not going to work. And you can see what the object is, you printed it out above - it's `datetime.datetime`, the *class*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to test if it is a datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime

time1 = datetime.now()
print(type(time1) is datetime)  # Outputs True
```

Comment: You should use `isinstance` (it supports inheritance correctly, for example), the OP's problem with using the correct tool is still unclear.

Comment: Using type works fine in this case. Unless you are using inheritance for datetime (which is highly unlikely) then type comparison will give an accurate answer no matter how OP imports the package. Using `isinstance` will also give True when comparing a datetime instance to `datetime.date` which probably is not the expected answer.

Comment: That's true, but the OP's reason for not being *able* to use `isinstance` is still deeply suspect and suggests they have other problems; until they edit with more information it's hard to say this solves all of them.