# How can I sort out an object is datetime or date in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to develop a logic that depends on the type of the input being date or datetime. To achieve this goal, I used `isinstance` with `datetime.date` and `datetime.datetime`. Unfortunately, it seems like that a `datetime.datetime` object is considered an instance of `datetime.date`.

```py
import datetime

date_obj = datetime.date.today()
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.now()


type(date_obj)
# <class 'datetime.date'>

type(datetime_obj)
# <class 'datetime.datetime'>


isinstance(date_obj, datetime.date)
# True
isinstance(datetime_obj, datetime.date)
# True


isinstance(date_obj, datetime.datetime)
# False
isinstance(datetime_obj, datetime.date)
# True
```

I suspected that `datetime.date` might be considered a subclass of `datetime.datetime` but that's not the case:

```py
issubclass(datetime.date, datetime.datetime)
# False
issubclass(datetime.datetime, datetime.date)
# True
```

What's the pythonic way of figureing out whether an object is a date or a datetime?

P.S. I checked [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151402/python-how-can-i-check-whether-an-object-is-of-type-datetime-date), but that doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: I think in your second snippet, you meant to write `issubclass(datetime.datetime, datetime.date)`, which is `True`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Comment: @buran thanks, seems like that solves this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the exact type of the objects with [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), and check whether it's `date` or `datetime` using `is`:

```
>>> type(date_obj) is datetime.date
True
>>> type(date_obj) is datetime.datetime
False

>>> type(datetime_obj) is datetime.date
False
>>> type(datetime_obj) is datetime.datetime
True
```

Note that [type objects are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33924950/11082165), so comparing them using `is` is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can check first for the wider type, then the other:

```py
if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
    # it's a date, not a datetime
    ...
elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
    # it's a datetime, not a date
    ...
```

Because every datetime.datetime object is also a datetime.date object, but the reverse is not generally true.